# Inside php file how to work with html quotes?

Tags: php, html

I have this html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-option delete po" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="<a class='btn btn-danger po-delete ajax-silent' href='#'>Yes im sure</a><button class='btn po-close'>No</button> 
<input type='hidden' name='td-id' class='id' value='id'>" data-original-title="<b>Really delete</b>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><a href="url" class="btn-option" data-toggle="mainmodal"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
```

And I want to print that on a php file something like that:

$a = array();
$a["button"] = 'here the html';

But the single quotes it brokes my code.

How I can do it in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat them using PHP's concatenation operator (`.`):

```
$a["button"] = 
'<button type="button" class="btn-option delete po" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="<a class='
. "'btn btn-danger po-delete ajax-silent' href='#'>Yes im sure</a><button class='btn po-close'>No</button> 
<input type='hidden' name='td-id' class='id' value='id'>"
. '" data-original-title="<b>Really delete</b>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><a href="url" class="btn-option" data-toggle="mainmodal"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>';
```

---

This will echo:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-option delete po" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="<a class='btn btn-danger po-delete ajax-silent' href='#'>Yes im sure</a><button class='btn po-close'>No</button> 
<input type='hidden' name='td-id' class='id' value='id'>" data-original-title="<b>Really delete</b>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><a href="url" class="btn-option" data-toggle="mainmodal"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array(); 
$a["button"] = "<button type='button' class='btn-option delete po delete ajax' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='left' >Yes sure</button>";
echo $a["button"];
?>
```

[code link](https://eval.in/705492)

Answer (score 0):

You can try other way also as follows :

```
<?php 
$a_tag = "<a class='btn btn-danger po-delete ajax-silent' href='#'>Yes im sure</a><button class='btn po-close'>No</button> <input type='hidden' name='td-id' class='id' value='id'>";
$a['button'] = '<button type="button" class="btn-option delete po" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="'.$a_tag.'" data-original-title="<b>Really delete</b>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><a href="url" class="btn-option" data-toggle="mainmodal"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>';
?>
```

I hope this will work